# Fast algorithm to access tiles in a circle in a tiled map based game

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I need a very fast algorithm to access the tiles that are in a disc.
I don't need a perfect disc, at the end, but I do **need a very fast** algorithm.

I know I can use a bounding square, and iterate through all the tiles in that square and then compute `x²+y²<R²` to determine whether or not the tile is in the disc. I my case, this is going to be very slow because I have to test thousands of circles per second, meaning millions of tiles, and testing `x²+y²<R²` on millions of tiles is slow.

I need something **fast**, even if it's not very accurate (=even if it's not a perfect disc, deformed)

Even an octagon (filled) would be ok, if it's fast enough.

Comment: I don't understand how the tiles are arranged in the circle / disc. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @vlad, presumably the tiles are tessellated infinitely on a plane, as if they were squares on graph paper. The OP then chooses a point and radius, and draws a circle on the plane. He wants to find all the squares lying inside that circle.

Comment: Are the radii of all your circles the same? If so, you can pre-calculate the contained tiles of a circle once, and use that data for all of your circles. You would only need to do a little addition to account for the change of position of the center of the circle.

Comment: @Kevin: Indeed the radii of all the circles are the same. But I don't understand what I should precalculate, and how to store it. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Testing millions of tiles per second should be just fine (assuming the tests aren't too computation-heavy). Your computer should be able to test up to about 10^8 tiles per second.

Comment: I suggest benchmarking any solution to see if it really results in a significant improvement. The possible improvement is limited, because more than 78% of the tiles in the bounding square are also in the disk.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think there's room for improvment because if we can somehow remove the test `(x²+y²<R²)`, which is applied on every tile of the square, it would be much faster.

Comment: @user1493046 Only if it is costly compared to the average per-tile work for the in-disk tiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to access the tiles in a matrix (game map) that are in a disc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034628/algorithm-to-access-the-tiles-in-a-matrix-game-map-that-are-in-a-disc)

Comment: @KateGregory this thread is focused on performance, when the other thread was only about the technic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x² + y² < R²` → `x² < R² − y²` so `x ∈ ( −√(R²−y²); +√(R²−y²))`

I think it is fast enough to calculate range just every line. If not, use Bresenham's algorithm to make it even faster.

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but it may not be clear that you need to iterate through the Y coordinates and calculate an X range for each.

Comment: You wrote `x ∈ (−√(R²−x²); +√(R²−x²))` when it should be `x ∈ (−√(R²−y²); +√(R²−y²))`

Comment: Thanks for bugreport!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through all the tiles and testing IF they lay in the circle region, why don't you go directly into the tiles that do in fact lay in the circle and add a flag and process as needed...

Using an octagon would perhaps be much cheaper but then you run in the problem of having to calculate the octagon width height and appropriate angles as the widths of the titles/region changes. The advantage to `x^2 + y^2` is the consistency.

Lastly, I would recommend looking into polar coordinates. `x = rcos(theta)` and `y = r*sin(theta)`. If you put all the values of `cos(theta)` and `sin(theta)` into an array, the program skips the necessary trig computation and jumps to directly testing the data. A quick google search will provide all necessary polar coordinate relationships.